# Using user inputs as a values in a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

Is there anyway to use input() as a value in a dictionary?
I have tried:

```
dictionary = {'1': input('Choose: [1]Red [2]Blue'), '2':input('Choose: [1]Green [2]Yellow')}
```

but this returns the first input:

```
'Choose: [1]Red [2]Blue'
```

Comment: Consider asking one question at a time, and properly describing what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: It does not return the first input. It displays the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Seems pretty straightforward.

```
>>> dictionary = {'1': input('Choose: [1]Red [2]Blue '), '2':input('Choose: 
[1]Green [2]Yellow ')}
Choose: [1]Red [2]Blue 1
Choose: [1]Green [2]Yellow 2
>>> dictionary
{'1': '1', '2': '2'}
>>>
```

For code clarity you're probably better off assigning `input(...)` values to variables,
and using the variables to construct a new dictionary.